# How can I customize the message after register?

Tags: users

How can I change, or customize, the message shown to the user after registration in Drupal 7?

> Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.

I tried the following [code](http://www.jayboodhun.com/changing-drupal-status-messages), but it didn't work for me.

```
function mymodule_message_alter(&$messages) {
  switch($messages->messages['status'][0]) {
    case 'Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.':
      $messages->messages['status'][0] = t('Your reset password instructions have been sent to your e-mail address. Please check your email and follow the instructions</p>');
    break;
  }

  // Disabling / Suppress all messages on a page and only display one Message
  if(arg(0) =='your-custom-page') {
    if($messages->messages['error']) {
      unset($messages->messages['error']);
      $messages->messages['error'][0] = t('This is my custom message to replace 10 system messages :) ');
    }
  }
  return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be overkill for a single message but the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module would work.

It includes a UI for quickly adding string replacements for anything that is passed through the `t()` function, which includes the message that you're trying to replace.

Comment: String overrides wont work, as it uses the same text as a password recovery notification.

Comment: @user6439 Not true, String Overrides works perfectly for this. The only place that specific message is set in core is in `user_pass_submit()`, with this line: `drupal_set_message(t('Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.'));`. As you can see, that has been passed through the `t()` function, so will work correctly with String Overrides.

Comment: It should also be noted the logintoboggan module also changes/sets messages after registration. For example in logintoboggan.module you can see messages such as `$message = t('Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.<br />Once it has been approved, you will receive an e-mail containing further instructions.');` and `$message = t('A validation e-mail has been sent to your e-mail address. In order to gain full access to the site, you will need to follow the instructions in that message.');`

Comment: I believe that for the string overrides module to work you need put the whole target whole message string into string overrides, not just a part of it. For example if the string you are trying to replace is over two lines you would need to include the <br /> tag. e.g. `'Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.<br />Once it has been approved, you will receive an e-mail containing further instructions.` was replaced correctly.