# How to completely disable 'further instructions sent to email' message after sign up

Tags: users

How to completely turn off/remove message 'Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.' that appears after registration? I'm using logintobogan module and I can see some customization than can be made to registration confirmation page, but none of these settings direct this particular message. It appears every time, also if I use redirection to completely custom thank you page?

Any idea?

Comment: Check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25134/how-can-i-customize-the-message-after-register

Comment: when I do what's instructed in this email (message set for logintobogan module) I then get two messages displayed - one default 'further instructions' and the other one setup in logintoboggan

Comment: Please [read this](https://www.drupal.org/node/257202) or [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/901518) .Hope this may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rules redirect the user to a pre-defined URL upon registration. This should over-ride whatever default behaviors you are seeing now...

- Back up your database.
- Enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
- Navigate to admin/configuration/workflow/rules
- Add new Rule

  ```
  Event: 'After saving a new user account'
  Action: 'Page Redirect' (optionally 'force redirect')
  ```